# How to correctly resize in Swift a textView when it has to fit all the screen?

Tags: swift, textview, resize, constraints, size-classes

[image]

I have a storyboard with two controls: a textView and a tableView. In some circumstances I move the tableView out of the screen and I resize the textView in a way that fits all the screen. The trailing of the textView (which is the element at the left side) equals the left of the tableView (which is the element at the right side) - 10.

When I hide the tableView of the screen I use this code to resize the textView:

```
        let tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame
        self.mainTextFieldTrailingConstraint.constant = mainTextFieldTrailingConstraint.constant + tableViewFrame.width
```

When I show the tableView, I use this code to resize the textView:

```
        let tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame
        self.mainTextFieldTrailingConstraint.constant = self.mainTextFieldTrailingConstraint.constant - tableViewFrame.width
```

All seems work fine when I run the code in portrait orientation but, if then I rotate the device in landscape orientation, the right edge of the field exceeds the right side of the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

when hiding tableview you need set size of textfield to full size of current view.

```
 self.mainTextFieldWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.width
```

Comment: Hi Ali Kıran, thank you for your answer, I implemented your code, unfortunately, when run, the right edge of the field exceeds the right side of the screen. There should be something I do wrong, I will review my code.

Comment: You should use width constraint with my code sorry I forget the mention it

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can and should do it with AutoLayout.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more. This is not a valid answer for Stack Overflow as it stands.

Comment: I Steven Xu, the project do uses AutoLayout, could you add more details to your answer please?